# cannot borrow as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference

Tags: rust

In order to get to know Rust a bit better, I am building a simple text editor and have the following structs:

```rust
struct File {
    rows: Vec<Row>,
    filename: Option<String>
}

impl File {
    fn row(&self, index: u16) -> &Row{
        &self.rows[index as usize]
    }

}

struct Row {
    string: String,
}

struct EditorState {
    file: File,
}
```

As you can see, I am keeping the state of an editor in a struct, which references the file, which contains a number of rows, which contains a string (Each of these structs has more fields, but I have removed the ones not relevant to the problem)

Now I want to make my rows editable and added this:

```rust
impl Row {
    fn insert(&mut self, at: u16, c: char) {
        let at = at as usize;
        if at >= self.string.len() {
            self.string.push(c);
        } else {
            self.string.insert(at, c)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I try to update the row:

```rust
//In the actual functon, I am capturing the keypress,
//get the correct row from the state and pass it and the pressed
// char to row.insert
fn update_row(mut state: &mut EditorState)  {
let row = &state.file.row(0);
row.insert(0, 'a');

}
```

This fails to compile:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*row` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
```

From the error, I can see that the issue is that Row should be mutable so I can edit it (which makes sense, since I am mutating it's String). I can't figure out a) how to be able to mutate the string here, and b) how to do this without having `row` always return a mutable reference, as in all other cases, I am calling `row` to read a row, and not to write it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That would give you an `&mut &Row`, which doesn't really help.

Comment: No, strike that. The `row()` function only returns a read-only reference, so you can't use that reference to modify the row. You need to add a `row_mut()` that returns a mutable reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a more idiomatic implementation for `File`:

```
impl File {
    fn row(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Row> {
        self.rows.get(index)
    }

    fn row_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<&mut Row> {
        self.rows.get_mut(index)
    }
}
```

Items of note here:

- Your implementation would panic if `index` is out of bounds. The idiomatic way of handling this is to return an Option, which `get` and `get_mut` allow you to get for free.
- Using u16 does not make much sense, as Vec is indexed using usize. Using `u16` is arbitrary here unless you really want to provide hard-coded limitations. In that case, I wouldn't rely on the type's max value but a constant instead that would make the intent clearer.

Comment: Thanks for a) answering the question, b) pointing me towards `get` and `get_mut`, and c) highlighting the `u16` issue, which really does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is impossible. You'll have to write two functions (note that I replaced `u16` with `usize` - there is no reason why you should limit yourself to 65536 characters per line):

```rust
fn row(&self, index: usize) -> &Row {
    &self.rows[index]
}

fn row_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Row {
    &mut self.rows[index]
}
```

Note that this is a common pattern across all Rust code. For example `Vec` has `get(idx)` and `get_mut(idx)`.

Answer (score 0):

File encapsulates row, so don't expose the row.
Instead implement methods in File to do something on the encapsulated row.

generally speaking, programs should have structure like

```
object.do_something()
```

in your case:

```
file.do_something_with_row(x)
```

instead of

```
let mut row = file.row_mut()
// do something with row here, rows leaking all over the place.
```