# Cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable (Rust)

Tags: rust

Goal Summary: I want to get rid of this error, and have my code to compile.

```text
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `selected` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:26
   |
16 | for tx in selected.iter_mut() {
   |           -------------------
   |           |
   |           mutable borrow occurs here
   |           mutable borrow later used here
17 |         tx.1.edges.push((selected[0].0.clone(), selected[1].0.clone()));
   |                          ^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `selected` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:49
   |
16 | for tx in selected.iter_mut() {
   |           -------------------
   |           |
   |           mutable borrow occurs here
   |           mutable borrow later used here
17 |         tx.1.edges.push((selected[0].0.clone(), selected[1].0.clone()));
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

Minimum Reproducible Code:

```rust
use std::time::{Duration};
pub struct Transaction {
    pub sender: String,
    pub receiver: String,
    pub amount: f64,
    pub signature: String, 
    pub status: &'static str,
    pub weight: u32,
    pub timestamp: (String, Duration),
    pub index: u32,
    pub edges: Vec<(String, String)>,}

fn main () {
    let mut selected: Vec<(String, Transaction)> = Vec::new(); 
    // The following vec has 2 items. 
    for tx in selected.iter_mut() {
        tx.1.edges.push((selected[0].0.clone(), selected[1].0.clone()));
        tx.1.status = "confirmed"}}
```

What I've tried:
[How do I fix cannot borrow `` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864719/how-do-i-fix-cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutabl/72884690#72884690)

[Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618823/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable)

[cannot borrow as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437256/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-as-it-is-behind-a-reference)

None of them really helped me, because either I'm not smart enough to understand or it just wasn't implementable for me. (I mean this in the case that even though we are getting the same errors, it's caused by different things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do in that loop, but if you just define `let edges = (selected[0].0.clone(), selected[1].0.clone())` before the loop (as it's not based on anything you're doing in the loop at all, there's no reason for you to do the borrow inside the loop), it should work.

```rust
let mut selected: Vec<(String, Transaction)> = Vec::new();
// Some stuff here, I assume, which populates `selected`
let edges = (selected[0].0.clone(), selected[1].0.clone());
for tx in selected.iter_mut() {
        tx.1.edges.push(edges.clone()); // or borrow?
        tx.1.status = "confirmed"}
}
```